# Find vectors $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ so that the frame $\{(1,1),(1,-1),(c,d),(a,b)\}$ is PRR equivalent to the frame

Tags: linear-algebra

Find vectors $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ so that the frame $\{(1,1),(1,-1),(c,d),(a,b)\}$ is PRR equivalent to the frame $\{(\sqrt{2},0),(0,\sqrt{2}),(\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}},\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}),(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}) \}$

PRR equivalent is permutation, rotation, and reflection equivalent. I understand that I can switch the order of the vectors but what do I do with that?

Comment: What are the lengths of the vectors in the "target" frame? What about those in the "source" frame? And what are the pairwise dot-products?

Comment: We haven't covered any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you haven't covered length or dot-product (which is more or less "cosine of angle between two vectors"), but without those, how are you defining "rotation"?

Anyhow, calling the first four vectors $u_1, \ldots, u_4$ and the others $v_1, \ldots, v_4$, so that $u_3$ and $u_4$ are unknown, I'm going to say that by reflecting through the x-axis (i.e., sending $y$ to $-y$) and rotating counterclockwise, we can turn $u_1$ into $v_1$ and $u_2$ into $v_2$. That means that the same operations have to turn $u_3$ into $v_3$. But 
$$
v_3 = \frac{\sqrt{4/3}}{\sqrt{2}} v_1 + 
\frac{\sqrt{2/3}}{\sqrt{2}} v_2,
$$
so it must be that 
$$
u_3 = \frac{\sqrt{4/3}}{\sqrt{2}} u_1 + 
\frac{\sqrt{2/3}}{\sqrt{2}} u_2 \\
= \sqrt{2/3}(1, 1) + \sqrt{1/3} (1, -1)\
= (\frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{3}}).
$$

I'll leave it to you to figure out what $u_4$ must be, by a similar argument.

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing. Especially how you are finding $v_3$. Can you please explain?

Comment: What I am thinking for the four vector is $(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{3}})$. Is this right?

Comment: That looks correct to me, yes. Glad you were able to work it out.